# fwrite keeps writing undesired text into my file

Tags: c

The output text file is only supposed to contain the contents of word1, but other things that are inside of my write function keep getting in there and I'm not sure why.

My main function:

```
int main(){

unsigned long size4;
char* word1 = "Hellllooooooo";
char* file_namee = "test.txt";
file_write(size4, word1, file_namee);

exit(0); 
}
```

Here is my file write function:

```
int file_write(unsigned long size, char *output, char *file_name2){


FILE *file;

file = fopen(file_name2, "wb");
if(file == NULL){
    printf("Cannot open file");
}

fwrite(output, 1, size, file);


fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);

size = ftell(file);
rewind(file);
return size;
}
```

Here is what it outputs and writes into test.txt:

```
Hellllooooooo test.txt rb Cannot open file  wb Cannot
```

Everything after "Hellllooooooo" is unexpected and I'm not sure why it's giving me that.

Comment: size4 is uninitialized

Comment: `size4` is uninitialized

Comment: You need to tell `fwrite` how many bytes to write and you don't do that.

Comment: You can (and should) check how many items were written by `fwrite`. Quote: *`fwrite` returns the number of full items actually written, which may be less than `count` if an error occurs.*

Answer (score 2):

You're using an uninitialized variable. That size parameter is not necessary if you're using C strings. Skip it and:

```
fwrite(output, strlen(output), 1, file);
```

`fwrite` needs to know the length of the buffer which can come in many forms, often raw, so the length parameter cannot be inferred. You must supply it, but as you're using C strings, you can use `strlen()` to compute.

Comment: Don't feel so bad. It's all about learning, and making mistakes is a great way to learn.